# generating a score for a domain with a keyword

Tags: python, string, function, readfile, writefile

I have keywords in my keyword.txt list and I have domains in my domain.txt list. I want to generate a score with a check. For example, if the keyword is apple, it will be 30 points, and I will search for it in all domains and give points for each domain. How do I do that ?

My code:

```
score_dict = {"apple":"30",
              "bananas":"50"}

def generate_score():
    with open("keyword.txt", "r") as file:
        keywords = file.read().splitlines()

    with open("domain.txt", 'r') as g:
        score = []
        for line in g:
            if any(keyword in line.strip() for keyword in keywords):
                score.append(line)
```

keyword.txt:

```
apple #if the domain contains the word apple, it will get a +30 score
```

domain.txt:

```
apple.com
redapple.com
paple.com
```

The output I want:

```
apple.com , 30
redapple.com, 30
paple.com, 0
```

Comment: How do you decide the score? As in, what is the score for, say, banana?

Comment: @Mortz I will determine the scores for the keywords.

Comment: Do you mean that for every keyword in `keywords.txt` that is part of a domain on `domains.txt` -  you assign 30 points?

Comment: @Mortz the importance of keywords will be different. eg: `banana` `+50 points`.

Comment: And is the importance mentioned somewhere? Is it in the `keywords.txt` file itself? Is it in a separate file? How are you planning to supply this value?

Comment: @Mortz no it has not been created yet. I just want sample for `apple`

Comment: `[(i.strip(), 30 if 'apple' in i else 0) for i in g.readlines()]`, but I suggest storing the score values in a dictionary, and then mapping it to the domains.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Can you check, I updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an iterative approach that loops the lines in `domain.txt` and searches for partial string matches from the dictionary:

```
score_dict = {"apple":"30",
              "bananas":"50"}

results = []
with open("domain.txt", 'r') as g:
    for domain in g.readlines(): #loop lines in domain.txt
        hit = None
        for substring, score in score_dict.items(): #loop score_dict
            if substring in domain:
                hit = True
                results.append({'domain': domain.strip(), 'substring':substring, 'score': score})
                break #break on hit to avoid unnecessary iterations
        if not hit: #assign score 0 if there is no hit
            results.append({'domain': domain.strip(), 'substring':substring, 'score': 0})
```

Output:

```
[{'domain': 'apple.com', 'substring': 'apple', 'score': '30'},
 {'domain': 'redapple.com', 'substring': 'apple', 'score': '30'},
 {'domain': 'paple.com', 'substring': 'bananas', 'score': 0}]
```

Note that this solution can be slow when working with large documents. In that case you could vectorize the issue using `pandas` with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
import pandas as pd

score_dict = {"apple":"30",
              "bananas":"50"}

df = pd.read_csv('domain.txt', names=['string']) #read domain.txt as pandas DataFrame
df['score']=(df['string'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(score_dict.keys())+')',expand=False).map(score_dict)).fillna(0)
df.to_csv('output.csv') # save output to csv
```

Results:

|  | string | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple.com | 30 |
| 1 | redapple.com | 30 |
| 2 | paple.com | 0 |